# Как поместить Fragment в Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer

Возможно ли, используя стандартные средства, сделать, чтобы при свайпе по экрану(как в случае с Navigation Drawer) выезжал другой фрагмент и перекрывал первый экран примерно на 80%, как это делает Navigation Drawer. При обратном свайпе или при нажатии на часть экрана, которая находится под фрагментом, выезжающий фрагмент прятался. Вообщем все как в Navigation Drawer, только с использованием полноценного фрагмента.
Если нельзя такое сделать стандартными средствами, то подскажите материал для изучения, чтобы можно было такое сделать самому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Точно так же как и с нефрагментом. Просто поместите фрагмент вместо `NavigationView` или того, что у вас используется в качестве бокового меню.

Само устройство `NavigationDrawer` просто располагает один из элементов разметки сбоку от основного c помощью атрибута `gravity`.